# interrupt priority control - Windows 10

Tags: irq

I am trying to figure out best interrupt priority for devices in Windows 10. I was able to find that users had good experience prioritizing cmos and gpu. That help me a lot reduce input lag.

I have currently cmos on priority 1, ehci 2, gpu 3 and i am trying to figure out, where to put system timer. Should system timer have priority before gpu, or ehci ? I have been testing multiple options, but not sure which i like best.

I wasn't able to find any article, or documentation, for to which priority put to system timer.

Any information would be helpful Thanks !

EDIT: Answering comment from @LMiller7: yes this refers to IRQ#Priority setting in this registry key: 
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl

If you put it like that yes it sounds like a dud.
To address relevance and credibility let me tell you this:
It may be outdated, but i assure you it still works. There are a lot of old registry tweaks that works actually. I was high ranked in competetive games and i tested myself how much of a difference in input lag i can tell by application on blurbusters forums. I can tell even 6 ms input lag. I am extreme sensitive for input lag, i can tell even smallest nuances.
Also there is extensive topic on overclockers forum that features this: https://www.overclock.net/forum/375-mice/1550666-usb-polling-precision.html
He even says you can tell difference up to 50us in handling interrupts from mouse polling. And yes: putting irq#priority for ehci into registry reduces input lag a lot! Also tested it with program he provided and had lower values, after applying that tweak, but is not so easy, as giving lower priority to something can cause deadlocks for other device, my ehci doesn't support msi-x for example. That's why i am asking, because i am unsure about that order, i usually go what feels best, but there are to many options.
Also there is a topic from some veteran on guru3d about msi and he has interrupt priority in his setting too: https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/windows-line-based-vs-message-signaled-based-interrupts.378044/
Unfortunately it is not written there - to which registry key it is reffering exactly.

I don't know if you know what system timer is, i don't know exactly how it works, but it basically interrupts system every x ms and forces update data to application. There is timer resolution app, which can reduce this windows up to 0.5ms, even between 1 and 0.5 ms it is big deal, because it doesn't have to wait another 0.5ms to update data to application like mouse movement and it stacks over time, resulting in much lower latency. Windows have to handle mouse polling, if time in which interrupt is supposed to be handled increases, it is big deal, if application has to wait another 1ms for it.  Since system timer doesn't handle hardware interrupts, but only updates data to the application. I am not sure what irq priority should i assign to it. Probably higher number,(higher number = lower priority), than for hardware/driver irqs. It makes sense to let system handle hardware irq first. What do you think ?
PS: sorry for indenting, it doesn't let me see preview when editing.

Comment: Are you referring to the IRQ#Priority setting? If so it hasn't been supported for a long time, if it ever was. Microsoft provides no documentation for it, official or otherwise. Nobody knows where it originated or can provide a convincing description of what it does. There is some evidence it was in NT 3.x, released more than 20 years ago, but if so it soon disappeared.

Comment: @LMiller7 I updated my answer in reaction to your comment.